# import packages in cordova plugin

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm building a plugin for a PDA3505 device, which must print texts using the integrated printer.

In the plugin's main Java file, I have this import: `import com.pda3505.printer.PrinterClassSerialPort;`

When I add the plugin to my app and try to make a build, I get this error:

`error: package com.pda3505.printer does not exist
import com.pda3505.printer.PrinterClassSerialPort;`

Where do I have to put the package for the plugin to work?

Comment: How far did you get with this? Im currently building a plugin too but my Java knowledge is very limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have .jar files for the PDA SDK, then you have to put it in a folder within the code and add a `lib-file` entry in the plugin.xml so it's copied to your project.

```
<lib-file src="src/android/libs/lib.jar"/>
```